# De un vector, me indica escoger los numeros mayores e imprimirlos junto con su posicion

Tags: java

el encabezado del ejercicio me solicita hacer un método que reciba un vector de enteros y mediante un mensaje, imprima los tres valores más grandes, además en que posiciones se
encuentra cada uno. Me permiten utilizar algún método de ordenamiento para
ayudarse.

```
 public String  metodoUno(int[] vectorNueve){
    String salida="";
    int indiceDelMayor = 0;
  // Recorrer arreglo y ver si no es así
  // (comenzar desde el 1 porque el 0 ya lo tenemos contemplado arriba)
  for (int x = 1; x < vectorNueve.length; x++) {
   if (vectorNueve[x] > vectorNueve[indiceDelMayor]) {
    indiceDelMayor = x;
   }
  }
  // Ahora podemos obtener el mayor usando la posición
  int mayor = vectorNueve[indiceDelMayor];
  salida="El mayor es: " + mayor + " y se encuentra en el índice " + indiceDelMayor;
  return salida;
 }
```

Lo que sucede con mi código es que solo logro imprimir un digito, cuando necesito imprimir todos los mayores

Mi otra consulta es, como puedo asignar en parametros los valores al vector, e intentado de muchas maneras, pero no lo he conseguido, y a la hora de imprimirlo, no me resulta.

```
    System.out.println(laboTres.metodoUno(vectorNueve[]));
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

si puedes usar cualquier método de ordenamiento los mas rápido seria usa Arrays.sort .el método sencillo y eficaz seria este,luego de usar sort elegimos los tres ultimos indices para obtener los tres numeros mayores del arreglo

```
public static String metodoTres(int []arreglo){
   String cadena ="";
   Arrays.sort(arreglo);
   
   for (int i=arreglo.length-1;i>arreglo.length-4;i-- ) {
    cadena+=String.valueOf(arreglo[i])+" ";
    
   }
    return cadena;

    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Te incluyo el código con dos formas de resolver el problema, una más avanzada que la otra, y ambas válidas:

```
package principal;

import java.util.*;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

public class Principal {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] numeros = {1, 10, 15, 3, 5, 7, 20, 1, 0, 60};
        var resultado = mayor3(numeros);
        System.out.println("resultado = " + resultado);
        
        List<Integer> slist = Arrays.asList(1, 10, 15, 3, 5, 7, 20, 1, 0, 60);  
        List<Integer> sortedList = slist.stream().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList());     
        
        sortedList.subList(Math.max(sortedList.size() - 3, 0), 
                sortedList.size()).forEach(System.out::println);;
        
        
    }

    public static List<Integer> mayor3(int[] numeros) {
        var max1 = 0;
        var max2 = 0;
        var max3 = 0;
        List<Integer> maximos = new ArrayList<>();

        for (var i = 0; i < numeros.length; i++) {
            if (numeros[i] > max1) {
                max3 = max2;
                max2 = max1;
                max1 = numeros[i];                
            } else if (numeros[i] > max2) {
                max3 = max2;
                max2 = numeros[i];
            }  else if (numeros[i] > max3){                
                max3 = numeros[i];
            }
        }

        maximos.add(max1);
        maximos.add(max2);
        maximos.add(max3);

        return maximos;

    }
}
```

Saludos desde HolaMundo!! xD

Comment: No sé quién te haya dado -1, pero te aconsejaría que explicaras las respuestas que aportes, qué se está haciendo y porqué. El sitio como tal no es para resolver los ejercicios de otras personas, si no, para resolver sus dudas y aconsejarlos. Como recomendación te sugiero leer [este artículo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Espero sigas participando en esta comunidad :)

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu consejo Eduardo! Lo tendré en cuenta. Lo del -1, pues no lo se, no pasa nada, alguien que no le habrá gustado la aportación. Simplemente quise aportar un par de opciones con las que obtener la solución al problema.